Internal server error when using Flashbot bundles
I tried to send_bundle function on sepolia net.
But these error occurs.
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/Eth-bundle/./bundle.py", line 199, in
main()`your text`
File "/home/Eth-bundle/./bundle.py", line 191, in main
tx = buy_bundle(private_keys, token_address, [0.005, 0.005])
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "/home/Eth-bundle/./bundle.py", line 157, in buy_bundle
send_result = w3.flashbots.sendRawBundle(
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "/home/Eth-bundle/env/lib/python3.11/site-packages/web3/module.py", line 75, in caller
result = w3.manager.request_blocking(
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "/home/Eth-bundle/env/lib/python3.11/site-packages/web3/manager.py", line 330, in request_blocking
return self.formatted_response(
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "/home/Eth-bundle/env/lib/python3.11/site-packages/web3/manager.py", line 293, in formatted_response
raise ValueError(error)
ValueError: {'code': -32000, 'message': 'internal server error'}

I want to implement uniswap v2 bundling using flashbots on Sepolia.
